# Use scriptaculous effects in jQuery code

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous

jQuery sliding animations are choppy unlike scriptaculous ones. So i want to replace my jQuery .slideUp/Down() with Scritaculous

Basically, use scriptaculous slideup/down in this code ->

```
jQuery('.button').on('click', function(){
jQuery('#box').slideUp();
});
```

Is it possible? if yes, what would be correct way to use sciptaculous slide in the code above?

**note:** i already have prototype.js included in the page and i DON't want to rewrite all my jquery code to prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the BlindUp method

and I would suggest attaching the event using prototypejs if you want to use scriptaculous on an element - you don't have to though.

Based on your example jquery code you are attaching to the click event for all of the `.button` class elements - equivalent code below.

```
$$(".button").invoke("observe","click",function(){
    $("box").blindUp()
});
```

http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-blindup/

Comment: oops there was a mistake in the code that would change the way that was handled - I've corrected it.